# Why VS 2010 running on .NET 3.5 Can NOT recognize the type in the code shown below inside the Global.asax file

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

The  C# code :

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(global_asax));
```

Of course, the required assembly(dll) log4net is already included in the project and that is visible from any pages except the GLOBAL.asax page. I really appreciate the help on this matter. I am assuming that I will have to change some settings in my VS 2010 installation.

partial global file code :

> <%@ Import Namespace="MRDDWV2.Common" %>
>   <%@ Application Language="C#" %>

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(global_asax));


void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Project.Core.NHibernate.Support.ConnectionStringManager.Instance.SetEnvironment(System.Environment.MachineName);
    string log4NetConfigFile = (string)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log4NetConfigFile"];
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath(log4NetConfigFile)));
}
```

Comment: have you tried to rebuild? are you using full or client .net 3.5?

Comment: rebuilds OK; but get run time error :  

Line 3:  <script RunAt="server" Language="C#">
Line 4:  
Line 5:      private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(global_asax));
Line 6:  
Line 7: 
 
full 3.5

Comment: can you post your whole global.asax file?

Comment: you should really have your code in a .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out what is going on looking at only at a partial file. But, I will venture to guess that since the class 'global_asax' is not in defined within the App_Code folder, the class is not available for reference (security reasons) within your aspx pages.

Still your problem is easily solved by using a string instead of typeof(...)

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("global_asax");
```